# Ruby on Rails Exception, no such column: microposts.user_id: SELECT

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations

Given the following code from the book `ruby on rails tutorial (rails 5)`

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :microposts
end

class Micropost < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user 
  validates :content, length: { maximum: 140 }
end
```

After executing actions in the console, I have such an error.

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid (SQLite3::SQLException: no such column: microposts.user_id: SELECT  "microposts".* FROM "microposts" WHERE "microposts"."user_id" = ? LIMIT ?)

Can someone please help me clarify what the problem is?

Comment: Can you include your migrations, as well as whether the migrations have been run?

Comment: check whether you missed to add user_id or association to user inside your microposts migration and also update code from `has_many :micropost` to `has_many :microposts` inside your **User** model

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For belongs_to association, you need a foreign_key in your table.

It seems that you have not added `user_id` column in a `microposts` table or if added then check whether migration is executed or not.

Also check the foreign key name is specified correctly

Comment: `ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 20180321141405) do

  create_table "microposts", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.text "content"
    t.integer "users_id"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  end

  create_table "users", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "name"
    t.string "email"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  end

end`

Comment: column name should be `user_id`  instead of  `users_id`

Comment: Now I get the error message "NoMethodError (undefined method" micropost "for # <User: 0x00005635b79482f0>
You meant? microposts
microposts =) '

Comment: change the association in model `User` as `has_many :microposts`

Comment: Changed, did not help.

Comment: please post the backtrace

Comment: Change did not help.

Comment: please post the backtrace of error in question itself.